# How to count string in td table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want count string in column **status**. But I don't know how to set the logic in javascript.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEbdd.png)

Comment: The question has nothing to do with `javascript`.

Comment: The description is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table id="resultTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Test Result</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="status">pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="status">fail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="status">fail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td class="status">pass</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
let table = document.getElementById("resultTable");
let status_td = table.querySelectorAll("td.status");
let p_counter = 0
let f_counter = 0

for (let i = 0; i < status_td.length; i++) {
  v = status_td[i].innerText
  if(v === 'pass')
  { p_counter += 1}
  else {f_counter += 1}
}

console.log(p_counter)
console.log(f_counter)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Thanh Phong, thank you for response my question.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: How can I count my td.status ? to find 'fail'

Comment: The variables p_counter and f_counter of the above code represent the number of passes and failures in the table, respectively